# How do I express my result as four-vector scalar products?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I have a term which looks like $\int \text{d}\Omega p_{1,\mu}p_{2,\nu}\text{Tr}(\{[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu],\gamma^\alpha\} A_\alpha )$, where $A_\alpha$ is a non-symmetrical matrix, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are momenta and d$\Omega$ is the angular part of $p_1$. I know that the result has to be Lorentz invariant, and therefore it is possible to express it as a scalar product of four-vectors.

So far, I only managed to express the result as components of $p_1$ and $p_2$. How can I express it only with four-vector products? I am not seeing how the terms with $\mu\neq\nu$ vanish, but I think they have to vanish because the result has to be Lorentz invariant.

Comment: What exactly is $A_\alpha$? Does it depend on the $p_\mu$? If not, why do you expect the result to depend on the momenta if they're the variables of integration?

Comment: $A_\alpha$ does not depend on the momenta. It is a lengthy product of $\gamma$ matrices and other matrices. Only over the angles of $p_1$ is integrated.

Comment: Are you sure this integration measure is Lorenz invariant ?

Comment: So the integration is just $\int d\Omega p_{1,\mu}$ ?

Comment: Is $A$ an even or odd product of gamma type matrices? Have you tried using the trace identities? For instance you can split the trace at the commutator into two traces and then continue to reduce it depending on what $A_{\alpha}$ is. Honestly at this level people usually turn to a CAS program to calculate the traces for them.

Comment: @Oбжорoв No there are other terms in the integration as well, but they are already expressed as four-vector scalar products so I left them out to make it less messy since the integration is not the part where I have problems with

Comment: @Triatticus $A_\alpha$ is an odd product (or else it would vanish). Using trace identities is hard since in A_\alpha there are also matrices which are not $\gamma$-matrices, that is why I right now just calculate the trace explicitly but then I have the problem that I just have tons of momentum components as a result and I can't see how to express them as scalar products.

Comment: @SolubleFish At least our professor told us that the result has to be Lorentz invariant

Comment: Was the problem specifically given this way? Is there a diagram that was being evaluated here? Was there more information given on how A acts in trace besides that it results in a zero trace by itself?